# Django fails user authentication

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql, python-3.x

Check user password fails after save

Django 1.11
postgres (postgis)

password hashes defined in settings.py

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher', ]
```

What I trying to do:

```
> ./manage shell
    In [1]: from accounts.models import User

In [2]: u = User.objects.get(pk=1)

In [3]: u.password
Out[3]: 'pbkdf2_sha256$36000$LlYFKXzibqZP$t7njfFLddkUos0ePjMTlSqM2KVhduFVvXTEobiHbXng=                                                   '

In [4]: u.check_password('123456')
Out[4]: False

In [5]: u.refresh_from_db()

In [6]: u.set_password('123456')

In [7]: u.password
Out[7]: 'pbkdf2_sha256$36000$WwQpAA6KyVX8$2GMy23BV1go4h/f/nlBezA50Jsc7QOi2sBlZsYhPAYM='

In [8]: u.check_password('123456')
Out[8]: True

In [9]: u.refresh_from_db()

In [10]: u.password
Out[10]: 'pbkdf2_sha256$36000$LlYFKXzibqZP$t7njfFLddkUos0ePjMTlSqM2KVhduFVvXTEobiHbXng=                                                   '

In [11]: u.check_password('123456')
Out[11]: False
```

Update: First I thought it because migrate database from mysql to postgres but even for reseting password

Comment: Use that example as it is better and more django-ish way: https://www.calazan.com/migrating-django-app-from-mysql-to-postgresql/

Comment: @EminMastizada I updated the question please reread.

Comment: You need u.save() after set_password

Comment: I did it ofcourse

Comment: I mean adding `u.save()` between `set_password` and `refresh_from_db`